# IcedTea 2.6.2 configuration: "llvm-config: error: components given, but unused"

Tags: llvm, icedtea

I'm configuring IcedTea 2.6.2 to build OpenJDK with ZeroShark. In order to make IcedTea I have installed the following dependency packages:

```
sudo apt-get install zip gawk xsltproc libjpeg8-dev libgif-dev libpng12-dev liblcms2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cups libcups2-dev libc6-dev libattr1-dev libalsa-ocaml-dev libsctp-dev libXtst-dev libffi-dev llvm-3.6-dev
```

Configuring IcedTea before making:

```
./configure --enable-zero --enable-shark --with-rhino=no
```

But I'm stuck on this step. Below is the output of the configuration:

```
    checking for llvm-config... /usr/bin/llvm-config
llvm-config: error: components given, but unused

usage: llvm-config <OPTION>... [<COMPONENT>...]

Get various configuration information needed to compile programs which use
LLVM.  Typically called from 'configure' scripts.  Examples:
  llvm-config --cxxflags
  llvm-config --ldflags
  llvm-config --libs engine bcreader scalaropts

Options:
  --version         Print LLVM version.
  --prefix          Print the installation prefix.
  --src-root        Print the source root LLVM was built from.
  --obj-root        Print the object root used to build LLVM.
  --bindir          Directory containing LLVM executables.
  --includedir      Directory containing LLVM headers.
  --libdir          Directory containing LLVM libraries.
  --cppflags        C preprocessor flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --cflags          C compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --cxxflags        C++ compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --ldflags         Print Linker flags.
  --system-libs     System Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
  --libs            Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
  --libnames        Bare library names for in-tree builds.
  --libfiles        Fully qualified library filenames for makefile depends.
  --components      List of all possible components.
  --targets-built   List of all targets currently built.
  --host-target     Target triple used to configure LLVM.
  --build-mode      Print build mode of LLVM tree (e.g. Debug or Release).
  --assertion-mode  Print assertion mode of LLVM tree (ON or OFF).
Typical components:
  all               All LLVM libraries (default).
  engine            Either a native JIT or a bitcode interpreter.
llvm-config: error: components given, but unused

usage: llvm-config <OPTION>... [<COMPONENT>...]

Get various configuration information needed to compile programs which use
LLVM.  Typically called from 'configure' scripts.  Examples:
  llvm-config --cxxflags
  llvm-config --ldflags
  llvm-config --libs engine bcreader scalaropts

Options:
  --version         Print LLVM version.
  --prefix          Print the installation prefix.
  --src-root        Print the source root LLVM was built from.
  --obj-root        Print the object root used to build LLVM.
  --bindir          Directory containing LLVM executables.
  --includedir      Directory containing LLVM headers.
  --libdir          Directory containing LLVM libraries.
  --cppflags        C preprocessor flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --cflags          C compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --cxxflags        C++ compiler flags for files that include LLVM headers.
  --ldflags         Print Linker flags.
  --system-libs     System Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
  --libs            Libraries needed to link against LLVM components.
  --libnames        Bare library names for in-tree builds.
  --libfiles        Fully qualified library filenames for makefile depends.
  --components      List of all possible components.
  --targets-built   List of all targets currently built.
  --host-target     Target triple used to configure LLVM.
  --build-mode      Print build mode of LLVM tree (e.g. Debug or Release).
  --assertion-mode  Print assertion mode of LLVM tree (ON or OFF).
Typical components:
  all               All LLVM libraries (default).
  engine            Either a native JIT or a bitcode interpreter.
checking for LLVMGetNextInstruction in -lLLVM-3.5.0... yes
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating hotspot.map
config.status: creating fsg.sh
config.status: creating jconsole.desktop
config.status: creating policytool.desktop
config.status: creating nss.cfg
config.status: creating linux.fontconfig.Gentoo.properties
config.status: creating javac
config.status: creating javap
config.status: creating javah
config.status: creating tz.properties
config.status: creating pax-mark-vm
config.status: creating remove-intree-libraries.sh
config.status: creating tapset/hotspot.stp
config.status: creating tapset/hotspot_jni.stp
config.status: creating tapset/jstack.stp
config.status: creating tapset/hotspot_gc.stp
config.status: executing depfiles commands
```

I'm using X86_64 ubuntu.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a very particular version of LLVM in order to use Shark. IIRC, it's something like 3.4 or similar (old) version.

Comment: I have already tried LLVM 3.4 and switched to the older IcedTea-2.5.6 but could not solve the problem. Knowing how llvm is checked here could probably tell us something about the cause of the problem. I've read the configure script but still cannot figure it out.